# User Login & Registration: can't register more than one user in C

Tags: c, authentication, registration

i'm working on this c project which deals with a user registration and login program. The problem is that the program was successful, but for only one user. Can you guys please explain what is wrong and what are the things that I should change? Thanks in advance.

P.S
This is my first question in stackoverflow

English isn't my main language

Anyways here's my code in C below:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int i=0;
struct w
{
char nama[30],pass[30];
}
w[100];
int n;
void login(void);
void reg(void);
int main(void)
{
menu:
system("cls");
printf("\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\tWELCOME!");
printf("\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t[ENTER]");
if(getch()==13)
{
    system("cls");
}
    else
{
    goto menu;
}
menu_main:
printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t[1] LOGIN\t\t[2] REGISTRATION\t\t[3] EXIT APP");
printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\t  INPUT YOUR SELECTION THEN PRESS [ENTER]: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
switch(n)
  {
    case 1: system("cls");
        login();
        break;
    case 2: system("cls");
        reg();
        break;
    case 3:system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tTHANK YOU FOR USING THIS APP\n");
        break;
    default: system("cls"); printf("\n\n\t\t\t\tNOT AVAILABLE");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\tPRESS ANY KEY TO GO BACK");
        getch();
        system("cls"); goto menu_main;
    }
}
void reg()
  {
    FILE *fp;
    char c,username[30]; int z=0;
    fp=fopen("file.txt","ab+");
    system("cls");
    printf("\n\n\t\tPLEASE INPUT USERNAME & PASSWORD");
    for(i=0;i<99;i++)
    {
      printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  USERNAME: ");
      scanf("%s",username);
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
          fread(&w[i],sizeof(w[i]),1,fp);
          if(strcmp(username,w[i].nama)==0)
            {
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t  USERNAME IS NOT AVAILABLE");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t  PRESS ANY KEY TO GO BACK");
            getch();
            system("cls"); reg();
            }
          else
          {
            strcpy(w[i].nama,username);
            break;
          }
        }
      z=0;
      printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  PASSWORD: ");
      while((c=getch())!=13)
        {
          w[i].pass[z++]=c;
          printf("%c",'*');
        }
      fwrite(&w[i],sizeof(w[i]),1,fp);
      fclose(fp);
      printf("\n\n\tPRESS [ENTER] IF YOU AGREE");
      if((c=getch())==13)
        {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\tYOU ARE REGISTERED!");
        printf("\n\n\t\tWOULD YOU LIKE TO LOGIN?\n\n\t\t  ");
        printf(" PRESS [1] FOR YES\n\n\t\t   PRESS [2] FOR NO\n\n\t\t\t\t");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if(n==1)
          { 
            system("cls");
            login();
          }
            else if(n==2)
          {
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\t\tTHANK YOU FOR REGISTERING IN THIS APP\n");
          } 
        }
        break;
      }
  }
  void login()
    {
      FILE *fp;
      char c,nama[10],pass[10]; int z=0;
      int cekun,cekpw;
      fp=fopen("file.txt","r");
      for(i=0;i<=10;i++)
      {
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  USERNAME: ");
        scanf("%s",nama);

        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  PASSWORD: ");
        while((c=getch())!=13)
        {
          pass[z++]=c;
          printf("%c",'*');
        }
        pass[z]='\0';
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
        fread(&w[i],sizeof(w[i]),1,fp);
          cekun=strcmp(nama,w[i].nama);
          cekpw=strcmp(pass,w[i].pass);
          if(cekun==0&&cekpw==0)
          {
            system("cls");
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tLOGIN SUCCESSFUL!");
            break;
          }
        else if(cekun==0)
          {
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tWRONG PASSWORD!");
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  (PRESS [Y] TO RE-LOGIN)");
            if(getch()=='y'||getch()=='Y')
              system("cls"); login();
          }
        else if(cekun!=0&&cekpw!=0)
          {
            h:
            printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tYOU ARE NOT REGISTERED\n \t\t\tPRESS [ENTER] TO REGISTER");
            if(getch()==13)
            system("cls"); reg();
          }
          else if(cekun!=0&&cekpw==0)
          {
            goto h;
          }
        }
        break;
      }
      getch();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think recursively calling `reg` is a good solution to a duplicate name. The rest of the _calling_ function will execute after the _called_ function finishes. It's going to be simpler to fail to register the name and make the user try again. Optionally make `reg` return 0 on failure, 1 on success, and you can just call it again.

Comment: A user can enter more than 30 characters for a password. You can fix this with an extra limit on the `while` loop that gets characters.

Comment: Don't write the username and password to the file until the user has agreed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason this doesn't work with multiple users is the logical structure of the `login` function.

```
while(!feof(fp))
{
    fread(&w[i],sizeof(w[i]),1,fp);
    cekun=strcmp(nama,w[i].nama);
    cekpw=strcmp(pass,w[i].pass);
    if(cekun==0&&cekpw==0)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tLOGIN SUCCESSFUL!");
        break;
    }
    else if(cekun==0)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tWRONG PASSWORD!");
        printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t  (PRESS [Y] TO RE-LOGIN)");
        if(getch()=='y'||getch()=='Y')
          system("cls"); login();
    }
    else if(cekun!=0&&cekpw!=0)
    {
        printf("\n\n\n\t\t\tYOU ARE NOT REGISTERED\n ...
```

This code is going to reject any login attempt unless the username and password match *the first entry in the file*.

Instead, you should implement the following logic:

```
for each entry in file
    if names match
        if passwords match
            login success
        else
            login failure
unknown user
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing functions that prompt and check, do the checking in a separate function.

For example, let's say you use

```
#define  MAX_NAME_LEN  31
#define  MAX_PASS_LEN  31

typedef struct {
    char  name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
    char  pass[MAX_PASS_LEN + 1];
} userinfo;
```

to store the information about known users.  Your user database could then be

```
#define  MAX_USERS  100

static userinfo  known_user[MAX_USERS];
static size_t    known_users = 0;
```

To register a new user, you write a function that takes the username and password as parameters:

```
int register_user(const char *user, const char *pass)
{
    const size_t  userlen = (user) ? strlen(user) : 0;
    const size_t  passlen = (pass) ? strlen(pass) : 0;
    size_t        i;

    if (userlen < 1)
        return -1; /* Empty username */
    if (userlen > MAX_NAME_LEN)
        return -2; /* Username is too long */
    if (passlen < 1)
        return -3; /* Empty password */
    if (passlen > MAX_PASS_LEN)
        return -4; /* Password is too long */

    /* Check if this user is already known. */
    for (i = 0; i < known_users; i++)
        if (!strcmp(user, known_user[i].name))
            return -5; /* Username is already registered. */

    if (known_users >= MAX_USERS)
        return -6; /* User database is full. */

    /* Add this user to the user database. */
    strncpy(known_user[known_users].name, user, MAX_NAME_LEN + 1);
    strncpy(known_user[known_users].pass, pass, MAX_PASS_LEN + 1);

    known_users++;

    return 0; /* Success */
}
```

Note that `(user) ? strlen(user) : 0` is a ternary expression.  It means that if `user` is not NULL, the expression evaluates to `strlen(user)`, otherwise it evaluates to 0.  (Yes, it is like a compact form of an `if` clause.)  It is common to see `strlen()` wrapped like this, because `strlen(NULL)` is not safe, and may crash the program: it is dreaded *Undefined Behaviour*, according to the C standard.  (They say *UB* may cause daemons fly out of your nose, but I think that's just a scary tale by the greybeards to make us take *UB* seriously.)

The `(!strcmp(...))` is equivalent to `(strcmp(...) == 0)`, and is true if the two strings match exactly.

Similarly, to check if the username and password pair matches a known user,

```
int verify_user(const char *user, const char *pass)
{
    const size_t  userlen = (user) ? strlen(user) : 0;
    const size_t  passlen = (pass) ? strlen(pass) : 0;
    size_t        i;

    if (userlen < 1)
        return -1; /* Empty username */
    if (userlen > MAX_NAME_LEN)
        return -2; /* Username is too long */
    if (passlen < 1)
        return -3; /* Empty password */
    if (passlen > MAX_PASS_LEN)
        return -4; /* Password is too long */

    for (i = 0; i < known_users; i++)
        if (!strcmp(user, known_user[i].name)) {
            if (!strcmp(pass, known_user[i].pass))
                return 0;  /* Valid user */
            else
                return -6; /* Wrong password */
        }

    return -7; /* No such user. */
}
```

At this point, you can write a small test program, and test if the above functions work. This is called [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing):

```
int main(void)
{
    int result;

    result = register_user("foo", "bar");
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "register_user(\"foo\", \"bar\") failed: %d.\n", result);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "register_user(\"foo\", \"bar\") worked as expected (0).\n");

    result = register_user("user", "pass");
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "register_user(\"user\", \"pass\") failed: %d.\n", result);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "register_user(\"user\", \"pass\") worked as expected (0).\n");

    result = register_user("foo", "irrelevant");
    if (result) {
        fprintf(stderr, "register_user(\"foo\", \"irrelevant\") failed. Expected -5, received %d.\n", result);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "register_user(\"foo\", \"irrelevant\") worked as expected (-5).\n");

    result = verify_user("no such", "user or password");
    if (result != -7) {
        fprintf(stderr, "verify_user(\"no such\", \"user or password\") failed. Expected -7, received %d.\n", result);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "verify_user(\"no such\", \"user or password\") worked as expected (-7).\n");

    result = verify_user("foo", "wrong password");
    if (result != -6) {
        fprintf(stderr, "verify_user(\"foo\", \"wrong password\") failed. Expected -6, received %d.\n", result);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "verify_user(\"foo\", \"wrong password\") worked as expected (-6).\n");

    result = verify_user("foo", "bar");
    if (result != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "verify_user(\"foo\", \"bar\") failed. Expected 0, received %d.\n", result);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "verify_user(\"foo\", \"bar\") worked as expected (0).\n");

    printf("All tests successful.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When you get better at programming, you can "automate" such testing using various ways.

Only when your test program works correctly for the tests (and do test both correct and incorrect inputs and their results!), continue onwards with solving the original problem.

That way, you know those two functions work, and you know that any issues or bugs must be elsewhere. (If you are not sure, you can add that input to the unit testing program, and verify!)

---

It is not a good idea to store passwords in plain text. Ever.  You don't need to do that, either.

What you should do, is use a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to convert the password to a large number; the hash function should be *cryptographically secure*. The password should be [salted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), too: a random number or string, that is saved as plain text, that is prepended (or appended or both) to the password, and the combination is supplied to the hash function.  To make any dictionary attacks slow, the hash function is usually applied a large number of times; this number can vary, but a fixed number of rounds is usually just as safe.

In this case, the user information is something like

```
#define  MAX_NAME_LEN  31
#define  HASH_SIZE     64    /* for 512-bit hashes like SHA512 */
#define  SALT_SIZE     16    /* for 128-bit salt */
#define  HASH_ROUNDS   5000

typedef struct {
    char           name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
    unsigned char  salt[SALT_SIZE];
    unsigned char  hash[HASH_SIZE];
} userinfo;
```

Let's say the cryptographically secure hash function we can use is declared as

```
void crypto_hash(unsigned char *hash, const void *data, const size_t size);
```

and we have a cryptographically secure random number generator that generates a random salt when we need one using

```
void crypto_salt(unsigned char *salt);
```

then our user registration function becomes

```
int register_user(const char *user, const char *pass)
{
    const size_t   userlen = (user) ? strlen(user) : 0;
    const size_t   passlen = (pass) ? strlen(pass) : 0;
    unsigned char *temp;
    unsigned char  hash[2][HASH_SIZE];
    size_t         i;

    if (userlen < 1)
        return -1; /* Empty username */
    if (userlen > MAX_NAME_LEN)
        return -2; /* Username is too long */
    if (passlen < 1)
        return -3; /* Empty password */

    /* TODO: Password strength checking! */

    /* Check if this user is already known. */
    for (i = 0; i < known_users; i++)
        if (!strcmp(user, known_user[i].name))
            return -5; /* Username is already registered. */

    if (known_users >= MAX_USERS)
        return -6; /* User database is full. */

    /* Generate a random salt for this new user. */
    crypto_salt(known_user[i].salt);

    /* Allocate a temporary buffer for the salt and the password.
       Here, for simplicity, we just prepend the salt to the password,
       and include the string-terminating nul byte, '\0'.
       This is to protect against a certain type of tail attacks. */
    temp = malloc(SALT_SIZE + pass_len + 1);
    if (!temp)
        return -8; /* Not enough memory. */

    /* Combine the salt and the password, including '\0' at end. */
    memcpy(temp, known_user[known_users].salt, SALT_SIZE);
    memcpy(temp + SALT_SIZE, pass, passlen + 1);

    /* First hashing round. */
    crypto_hash(hash[0], temp, SALT_SIZE + passlen + 1);

    /* The temporary buffer is no longer needed.
       We wipe, then free it. */
    memset(temp, 0, SALT_SIZE + passlen + 1);
    free(temp);

    /* Repeated rounds. */
    for (i = 0; i < HASH_ROUNDS - 2; i++)
        crypto_hash(hash[(i+1) & 1], hash[i & 1], HASH_SIZE);

    /* Final round. Since i was incremented after the last
       crypto_hash() call, the last hash is in hash[i & 1]. */
    crypto_hash(known_user[known_users].hash, hash[i & 1], HASH_SIZE);

    /* Wipe the temporary hash table. */
    memset(hash[0], 0, HASH_SIZE);
    memset(hash[1], 0, HASH_SIZE);

    /* Add this user to the user database. */
    strncpy(known_user[known_users].name, user, MAX_NAME_LEN + 1);
    known_users++;
    return 0; /* Success */
}
```

Two temporary hash slots are used, because usually the `crypto_hash()` functions expect the result to be somewhere else than the source is.

User name and password check becomes

```
int verify_user(const char *user, const char *pass)
{
    const size_t   userlen = (user) ? strlen(user) : 0;
    const size_t   passlen = (pass) ? strlen(pass) : 0;
    unsigned char *temp;
    unsigned char  hash[2][HASH_SIZE];
    size_t         i, u;
    int            result;

    if (userlen < 1)
        return -1; /* Empty username */
    if (userlen > MAX_NAME_LEN)
        return -2; /* Username is too long */
    if (passlen < 1)
        return -3; /* Empty password */

    for (u = 0; i < known_users; i++)
        if (!strcmp(user, known_user[u].name))
            break; /* u will be less than known_users */
    if (u >= known_users)
        return -7; /* No such user */

    /* known_user[u] matches the name. */

    /* Allocate a temporary area for combining this users' salt
       and the supplied password. */
    temp = malloc(HASH_SIZE + passlen + 1);
    if (!temp)
        return -8; /* Out of memory. */

    /* Combine the salt and the password the same way as when
       the user and password was registered. */
    memcpy(temp, known_user[u].salt, SALT_SIZE);
    memcpy(temp + SALT_SIZE, pass, passlen + 1);

    /* Calculate the hash the same way. First pass: */
    crypto_hash(hash[0], temp, SALT_SIZE + passlen + 1);

    /* Temporary buffer is no longer needed, so clear and free it. */
    memset(temp, 0, SALT_SIZE + passlen + 1);
    free(temp);

    /* Repeated rounds, including the final round. */
    for (i = 0; i < HASH_ROUNDS - 1; i++)
        crypto_hash(hash[(i+1) & 1], hash[i & 1], HASH_SIZE);

    /* Because i was incremented after the last crypto_hash() call,
       hash[i & 1] is where the final hash is. Compare. */
    if (!memcmp(hash[i & 1], known_user[u].hash))
        result =  0; /* Valid password for the user! */
    else
        result = -6; /* Wrong password. */

    /* Wipe the temporary hash buffer. */
    memset(hash[0], 0, HASH_SIZE);
    memset(hash[1], 0, HASH_SIZE);

    return result;
}
```

In a practical application, it is best to *not* differentiate between *"unknown user"* and *"wrong password"*, because knowing which usernames are valid, can make certain attacks easier.